# How can I show only one specific div from an entire page?

Tags: html, css

If I have something like this:

```html
<div class="layout" background-color="#363636">
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://example.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://example2.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://exampl3.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://exampl4.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://exampl5.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://exampl6.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://exampl7.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can hide everything  else (including the layout div) except for the element with attribute data-src="https://exampl4.com" using only CSS?

Comment: If you hide the **layout** div then everything inside it will also get hidden, including the div that you want to be showing. That is how HTML and CSS work, by definition.

Comment: You cannot hide the parent div, layout, and display any children inside that div. If what you want to do is only show the specific card you mentioned, you can use css like this:

.card > div:not([data-src="https://exampl4.com"]) {
  display: none;
}

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[data-value: "exact value"]` to select elements with data attributes in CSS. Here is a [blog](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/) about it.

However, you can't use `display: none` on the parent as it will override the child elements display property. And it isn't even needed as there will be nothing else except the `div` you wanted to display.

```css
.card > *{
  display: none;
  }
.card > [data-src="https://exampl5.com"]{
  display: flex;
 }
```

```html
<div class="layout" background-color="#363636">
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://example.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://example2.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://exampl3.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://exampl4.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://exampl5.com">Hello world 5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://exampl6.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://exampl7.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to hide the the parent using **visibility : hidden;**. Create new class for the desired child, select the element from the parent and set the properties to **visibility : visible;**

```css
.layout{
  visibility : hidden;
}

.layout > .card-visible {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout" background-color="#363636">
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://example.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://example2.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://exampl3.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card card-visible">
    <div data-src="https://exampl4.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://exampl5.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://exampl6.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://exampl7.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It should be noted that **space will still be allocated** for all elements when using `visibility : hidden;`. The content will disappear but surrounding elements will be positioned as if everything was being shown.

Comment: I cannot edit the code since i am webscraping

Answer (score 0):

You can hide every element with `visibility: hidden` and then use a css-selector to only show the elements with the correct data-attribute:

```css
.card > div[data-src="https://exampl4.com"] {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

*A detailed guide about attribute selectors can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).*

If you want that none of the hidden elements takes up any space of the page, use `display: none` and `display: block` instead of `visibility`.

**Here‘s an example with `visibility`:**

```css
.card > div {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.card > div[data-src="https://exampl4.com"] {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout" background-color="#363636">
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://example.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://example2.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://exampl3.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://exampl4.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://exampl5.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://exampl6.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://exampl7.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**And Here‘s an example with `display`:**

```css
.card > div {
    display: none;
}
.card > div[data-src="https://exampl4.com"] {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout" background-color="#363636">
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://example.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://example2.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://exampl3.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://exampl4.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://exampl5.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://exampl6.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div data-src="https://exampl7.com">Hello world</div>
  </div>
</div>
```